# Google App Engine: Only serve existing files in static directory

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to only serve existing files in a static directory? For example in my `app.yaml` file I have

```
- url: /img
  static_dir: img
```

Which works fine if you go to `/img/exists.jpg`. However if you go to `/img/doesnt-exist.jpg` you get an ugly *Error: Not Found* message. Is there a way to make it skip this file and go to this script so that I can add a custom 404 message?

```
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Although what you're asking isn't doable in `app.yaml` but since you're giving an example of images you might want to take a look at the `onerror` event the `<img>` tag triggers when it fails to load an image so you can load a different one. This isn't GAE related and works on client side browser only though. See more: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

Answer (score 0):

According to the current documentation, you can [configure a custom error response](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses).

Comment: Yeah I saw that, unfortunately not quite what I am looking for as it only lets you serve a static html page. Also not sure if it is even supports 404 messages? It says it just supports over_quota, dos_api_denial, and timeout.

Comment: I understand that this is not want you want, but this is the official documentation :(  The only other option you have is not to treat these files as static, but have a script that processes requests for these files. This is a major setback in terms of performance and user experience, though, so I would recommend using it only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately I've found parts of the official documentation to be quite poor and is often missing information hence the question. I'll leave this up for a bit just in case anyone else has any insights and I'll double check that it works for 404s and then I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks for your help.